# Where should we save Api config in chrome extension to be safe?

Tags: firebase, google-chrome-extension

I'm working with my first chrome extension, and this extension needs to work with firebase. So I need to have my firebase config data somewhere in my extension and the question is where?

As can I see official firebase quickstart:
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/chromextension/credentials.js

config to Api is in credentials.js and background.js, but why in credentials.js (it's popup)? As I can see user can inspect popup code and see all credentials.js script with config data. Background.js is better to that task?

Second question is how to secure is save some data (for example uid of logged in user) in locale storage?

Comment: There's no secure storage since the user can inspect anything the extension contains or stores. Either directly in a file manager or in devtools for each component of the extension including the background script page.

Comment: So it's not possible to prepare browser extension with firebase safely? No extensions work with the backend solutions like firebase, azure etc?? :/ Don't understand why official firebase (google) recomendation is to set config data in these files if it is not secure?

Comment: Because nothing stored locally is really secure against an inquisitive and knowledgeable local user unless it's encrypted remotely so there's no point in protecting the API keys.